# jQuery not working even with $.noconflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having problem running the following script in my application. The action is not working I tried altering the script in the following ways

**Test 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.deleterd').on('click', function(){
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
});
</script>
```

**Test 2**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();
      (function( $ ) {
       $('.deleterd').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('div').remove();
     });
    </script>
```

**Test 3**

```
  jQuery(function($) {
    $.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.deleterd').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
```

Tried with no conflict, without no conflict but still the script is not working.

**When I paste the same script in the console then the script is working fine. I tried placing the script in the top, bottom, middle of other scripts but still no use. Any help is highly appreciated.**

***No, still not working. Also, I am getting an error in the browser console as "TypeError: Undefined is not a function"***

Comment: whether the element `deleterd` is added dynamically? try `jQuery(document).on('click', '.deleterd', function () {
    jQuery(this).closest('div').remove();
});`

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Yes, its added dynamically and your code is working :) Thank you very much

Comment: so there is no need to use no conflict... just use event delegation

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing braces.. try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.deleterd').on('click', function(){
        $(this).closest('div').remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: No, still not working. Also, I am getting an error in the browser console as "TypeError: Undefined is not a function"

Comment: is it '.deleterd' or '.deleted' ?

Comment: at which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Its `.deleterd` and its correct only.

Comment: Why are you using `$` after calling `noConflict()`?